# How to make the search box and search icon stick together

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:-

```
    <div class="input-append">
       <input id="txtSearchByLocation" name="searchTerm" type="text" class="" placeholder="Search By Location" style="padding-left: 14px;">
       <button id="btn-submit-search" class="btn" type="submit" onclick="searchByLocation()"><span class="icon-search"></span></button>
   </div>
```

The search button and search text don't stick together. How do I manage to do that ?

Comment: what do you mean by "stick together"?

Comment: For "stick together", you mean both the search button and the search text will look visually as if both were united, like, for example, the input groups in Bootstrap ([BS4 docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the border of the input to transparent and style the button to your taste, and set outline transparent to disable to the "blue" outline when selecting input elements and wrap them in inside the div. Like the snippet below.

```css
.btn{
    border-left: 2px solid #929292;
    border-right: transparent;
    border-top: transparent;
    border-bottom: transparent;
    height: 36px;
    outline: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;  
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;  
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out; 
    background-color: #9e9e9e;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #333;
}
.btn:hover{
    background-color: #00B6FA; 
}
.input-append{
    border: 2px solid #929292;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
}
#txtSearchByLocation{
    outline: transparent;
    border: transparent;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 10px;
    height: 33px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-append">
  <input id="txtSearchByLocation" name="searchTerm" type="text" class="" placeholder="Search By Location" style="padding-left: 14px;">
  <button id="btn-submit-search" class="btn" type="submit" onclick="searchByLocation()">SEARCH</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> </span>
<input id="search" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="enter your query" type="text" required>
```